# C# Define multiple COM ports and settings in configuration file

Tags: c#, serial-port

Im trying to make my software choose witch com ports to use from the Configuration file.
I haven't had any luck so far, just to be clear, im just a newbie in C# but eager to learn more.
I have 4 com ports that will send a command to various micro controllers.
So far i have been using this code to define witch com ports to use and its settings:

```
SerialPort SerialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
SerialPort SerialPort2 = new SerialPort("COM2", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
SerialPort SerialPort3 = new SerialPort("COM3", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
SerialPort SerialPort5 = new SerialPort("COM4", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
```

And an button to trigger it:

```
  private void button1_ON_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       try
        {
            if (!(SerialPort1.IsOpen))
                SerialPort1.Open();
            SerialPort1.Write(new byte[] { 0xFF, 0x01, 0x01 }, 0, 3);
            SerialPort1.Close();
            timer1.Interval = 500;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error writing to serial." + ex.Message, "OH NO AN ERROR!!");
        }



    }
```

I have read a lot into create a config file to define its values, but i just cant seem to get it to work with the serialport.
Have you got any suggestions how to implement this to my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can put the active port's number (port that is to be used) in `appSettings` section of config file. Then you can use `ConfigurationManger` class to get values from app settings.

**Config File:**

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="activePort" value="COM3" />
</appSettings>
```

**Code:**

```
var port=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["activePort"]
```

For multiple ports you can use comma separated values like "COM1,COM3" and then split it.

For more information check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) MSDN page: